# can I change the data type for a column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, primary-key

The created table, but the type of the primary key is not preserved.
Now it looks like this:
id integer is NOT NULL, -
Can I change to the primary key in the created table?

```
ALTER TABLE analytics.import_property_objects_copy ALTER COLUMN ID TYPE SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
```

Comment: That is not a valid SQL statement. Can you tell us a) how your table was defined before and b) what you want to achieve?

Comment: What do you mean with "not preserved"? [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) `serial`  is not a data type, but just a shortcut for an `integer` that gets its default value from a sequence.